# Continuity of the stochastic process $X_t=\int_{0}^{t}(a+b\frac{u^n}{t^n} ) dW_{u} $

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am wondering about the continuity of the stochastic process

$$X_t=\int_{0}^{t}(a+b\frac{u^n}{t^n} ) dW_{u} $$

Where n=1,2,..
At t=0, there seems to be a discontinuity except for b=0 . Is there a discontinuity?

Comment: Have you tried adapting the solution you were given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3434889/388944)?

Comment: @Theoretical Economist I adapted it and I did it for the general case. Please do upvote the question and the answer I have posted here.

Comment: Hi there, I can't think of anything that generalizes this. But I spent a long time trying to get a better look at a different way of proving continuity : have you seen the Kolmogorov-Chentsov theorem? Essentially, bounding moments of $|X_t - X_s|$ in terms of $|t-s|$ leads to a process that can be made Holder-continuous in fact. I think we can use this to prove that the given process is Holder $\frac 12$ continuous, but I struggled to work out the details. I really must apologize to you, since I had wrongly informed you on the bounty below, as well as been unable to contribute.

Comment: Having said that , do look to apply Kolmogorov-Chentsov. For an integral of the form $s \to \int_{0}^s \sigma(t,W_t)dW_t$ which doubles up as a martingale, I would suggest you try the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality, which along with a standard Holder inequality application provides a nice way to bring the stochastic difference in terms of the difference of indices. I will keep working in this direction.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг I have edited my answer to include the case of f(u, t) of the b(u) /g(t). Also the X_t given in the question can be shown to be normally distributed for the general a and b and even with variance t for a^2+b^2/3+ab=1 (an affine ellipse). Then Kolmogrov-Chentsov theorem can be applied to it exactly like for Wt and thus it can be shown to be holder 1/2 continuous and hence can also be shown to be wiener process for those a, b.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг You don't need to apologize I was just teasing you about the bounty thing before I wasn't serious about that.I am just glad to discuss this with you. And also thanks a lot for upvoting the question and the answer.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг I will also try to apply Kolmogorov Chentsov theorem to $\int_{0}^{s}\sigma(t,W_t)dW_{t}$

Comment: @Human thank you once again, and yes, to apply KC to this stochastic integral you require BDG inequality. It is really beautiful how things work out.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг I am sorry my claim in the previous comments was wrong. I made an error in my calculations. Anyway I have added all those details to my (again) edited answer. I have shown it be holder<1/2 continuous for restricted a, b.

Comment: Very nice, the edits make sense, I took great pleasure in reading the answer .

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг Thanks that means a lot to me.

Comment: You are welcome. If you continue to post questions, then I will track your progress, and attempt them all. I am at a formative stage (just learnt the Ito integral recently by myself) so I needed to do some big reading up while checking out your question. Thanks once again.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг I am actually also a beginner at this(first time for continuous stochastic processes). But I am attending (weekly)lectures on Ito calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem comes down to showing the continuity of

$$\frac{1} {t^n}\int_0^t u^n dW_u $$

From  Itô's formula, we have

$$\frac{1} {t^n}\int_0^t u^n dW_u =W_t-\frac{n}{t^n}\int_{0}^{t}W_u u^{n-1}du$$

So essentially we have to evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t^n}\int_{0}^{t}W_u u^{n-1}du$$

Where n is any natural number 
Since $W_u u^{n-1}$ is continuous a.s thus from the fundamental theorem of calculus and L'Hôpital's rule, we have

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t^n}\int_{0}^{t}W_u u^{n-1}du=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{W_{t}t^{n-1}}{nt^{n-1}}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{W_{t}} {n} =0$$
a.s
Thus $$X_t$$ is continuous a.s

More generally for the stochastic process

$$Y_t=\int_{0}^{t}f(u,t)dW_{u}$$
Where f is of the form 
$$f(u, t) =\frac{b(u)} {g(t)} $$
From  Itô's formula, we have

$$f(t, t)W_{t} - f(0,t)W_{0}-\frac{1}{g(t) }\int_{0}^{t}\frac{db} {du} W_{u} du$$

If $\frac{db} {du}$  is continuous then

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{g(t) }\int_{0}^{t}\frac{db} {du} W_{u} du=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{b' (t)} {g'(t)} W_{t} $$

Thus sufficient(but not necessary)  conditions for continuity at t=0 are

$$f(t, t)$$ is continuous
$$f(0,t)$$ is continuous 
$$\frac{db} {du}$$  is continuous
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{b' (t)} {g'(t)}$$ exists and is finite

Bonus:Check this for $$f(u, t) =\frac{\sin(u)} {t}$$

For the stochastic process $X_t$ given in the question, certain a,b can make it a Wiener process

We have already established $X_0=0$  a.s.
Note that X_t has mean 0 and variance
$(a^2+\frac{b^2}{2n+1}+\frac{2ab}{n+1})t$
and it is normally distributed since the limit of a sequence of normal random variables is also a normal random variable.

For its variance to be t 
 $(a^2+\frac{b^2}{2n+1}+\frac{2ab}{n+1})=1$

Also note that since $X_t-X_s$ and $X_s$ are jointly normally distributed(any of their linear combination is individually normally distributed)  and their covariance vanishes for
$b=0$
and
$\frac{a} {n+1}+\frac{b}{2n+1}=0$
These equations determine the a, b e.g two of the solutions are
$a^2=1, b=0$
Hence $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $ X_s$ for these a, b.

Now since

$|X_t-X_s|=|t-s|^{\frac{1}{2}}Z$

Where Z is the standard normal random variable and the equality is in distribution. Then

$E|X_t-X_s|^{2m}=C_{m} |t-s|^{m} $

Thus from the Kolmogorov continuity theorem $X_{t} $ is a.s $<\frac{1}{2}$ holder continuous for those a, b.

These conditions make $X_t$ a Wiener process for those a, b.

Comment: Looks ok to me…

Comment: I would think this is fine. You should award the bounty.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг who should I award the bounty to?

Comment: Award it to yourself. You can do that, right?

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг I am not sure if I can but I will find out after two days when the grace period for this question comes

Comment: Well, I've done it  with my own question, so you can do it with yours. Wait for the grace period. There may be another answer, but this is good enough.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг Thanks for the info that's interesting so apparently there is a loophole to the bounty being 'nonrefundable'

Comment: Forgive me, I realized I was able to accept my answer but not give it the bounty! However, I hope somebody will be able to generalize your result on this being continuous.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг Oh come on you got my hopes up for no reason. Also I am not sure how this can be generalized.

Comment: Certainly there can be generalizations . It seems you have a condition on $f$ for which $t \to \int_0^t f(u,t)dW_u$ is continuous everywhere, and I shall think about this.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг I didn't think that far but that's an interesting question Can you think of some counterexamples of such f(u, t)?

Comment: I will get back, I need to revise the Ito integral for this one!

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг  Never mind I just though of one with 1/sin(t)  but rational functions f(u, t) seem to work fine

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг  I just saw your recent comment. I will be glad to go over  this further after you've revised.

Comment: +2, I am happy that I hav something to think about. I will get back to you by say tomorrow?

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг the rational function thing is wrong too. The power of t in the denominator needs to bounded by that of u in the numerator  or else it is discontinuous.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг the rational function thing is wrong too. The power of t in the denominator needs to bounded by that of u in the numerator  or else it is discontinuous.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг again I just saw your recent comment after my comment anyway yes tomorrow is fine