# Continuity of the stochastic process $X_t=\int_0^t(a+b\frac{u}{t}) \, dW_u$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am wondering about the continuity of the stochastic process
$$X_t=\int_0^t \left(a+b\frac{u}{t}\right)\,dW_u$$

which has variance $t$ and normally distributed for
 $a^2+\frac{b^2}{3}+ab=1$

The process seems to be discontinuous at $t=0$ except for $b=0.$ 
Is this stochastic process really discontinuous or does the limit $t\to 0$ have a finite value

Comment: Wouldn't the limit have to be zero since $\int_0^0 \text{(anything)}=0$?

Comment: @Math1000 not quite even in real analysis there are many counterexamples for this e.g $\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t du $ has the limiting value 1 for t=0

Comment: @Math1000 : That means the value of the function at that point is $0,$ not that the limit of the function at that point is $0.$ If the value of the function were always equal to the limit of the function, then why would we even bother having the concept of limits? $\qquad$

Comment: @Math1000 similarly  the integral u^{-1/2}  by t which gives infinity as the limit for t=0

Comment: For the function to be continuous at $0$, the value of the function at the point $0$ must equal the limit. That is what I meant.

Comment: @Human Can we consider the map $t\mapsto \frac 1t \int_0^t \ \mathsf du$ continuous at zero considering it is not defined at zero? I agree that the limit exists and is nonzero; that is not what I am getting at here.

Comment: @Math1000 then the same thing goes for $\frac{\sin(x) }{x} $ at x=0  or any other function with indeterminate form at some point. What I am asking then is that can we define the function at t=0 such that it is continuous? For the example I gave yes but the one in the question? I have got no clue. I guess what I am asking whether it a removable or essential discontinuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align*}X_t&=\int_0^t \left(a+b\frac{u}{t}\right)\,dW_u \\\\ &=aW_t + \frac{b}{t}\int_0^t u\, dW_u\end{align*}$$

Using Itô's formula we get:
$$\int_0^t u\, dW_u = tW_t - \int_0^t W_s\, ds$$
and so
$$X_t = (a+b)W_t - \frac{b}{t}\int_0^t W_s \, ds$$

We know: $W_s$ is continous a.s. hence from the Fundamental theorem of calculus it follows that $$\int_0^t W_s \, ds$$ is differentiable a.s. in $t=0$ which means nothing else that $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t W_s \, ds$$ exists a.s.

All together we get: $$\lim_{t \to 0} X_t = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{b}{t}\int_0^t W_s \, ds$$ exists a.s. and so $X_t$ is continous in $0$.

Comment: Great solution I had already put a bounty for this other question so you could do that if you want.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3430941/691295

Comment: That's the link

Comment: I wonder if it's always true if we keep on adding more terms of the form u^n/t^n

Comment: Why do you open the same question twice?? And: Why don't you try to adapt the solution to the case $\frac{u^n}{t^n}$?

Comment: I didn't open the same question twice i am satisfied with this answer i asked the one in the link before this question was asked and  I was able to put a bounty on it I thought that might have worked  in getting me the answer faster(I was growing impatient) but in the end the one I didn't put a bounty on got answered I just don't want that bounty to go to waste so I added an extra u^2/t^2 term to the question and edited the original question in the link I don't really need the answer for that one I will try it myself and adapt the solution you showed me for that one  Anyway Thanks

Comment: I adapted the solution you gave here for the general case and posted it on stackexchange here

Comment: this is the link   https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3430941/691295

Comment: I couldn't have done the general case without this solution you posted so thanks and also please do upvote the question and the answer I provided in the link if you like it